# How to configure S3 for Amazon Skill Flow Builder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have my Skill deploying successfully via Amazon's new `Skill Flow Builder` and the `ASK CLI` tools.

In the `abcConfig` file there's the option to add an `S3` bucket for use with the Polly service. I've created a bucket and set the permissions so it is publicly available. I believe this is done correctly, but it is difficult to tell if the lambda function is finding the bucket and using it. When I test the lambda it shows the URL that it has constructed using these settings from the config:

```
"s3-domain-name": "s3.amazonaws.com",
"s3-bucket-name": "<BUCKET NAME>",
```

... but the audio file is not found on the device. I think this is because it isn't the correct public URL for the file.

So, my question is, what would be the correct format for the domain name to ensure that it is hitting the bucket that I created?

UPDATE

I get this error when loading the URL that the Lambda test returns:

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<Endpoint>**********.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<Bucket>**********</Bucket>
<RequestId>6FBBDF******DC89</RequestId>
<HostId>
i7op6+RMyiHAcf*********LW58FSOKIily2ouNg3L/bp8IV0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

UPDATE UPDATE
I have discovered this warning in the Lambda role policy screen:
[image: lambda policy]

This suggests that it can't create the objects in the S3 bucket (hence the error reading the URI).

Unfortunately, when I edit the policy to allow object resources, I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The Amazon Skill Builder documentation is incorrect. When you setup the policy for the `SFB Lambda` account you need to make sure you give it `"s3:PutObjectAcl"` actions as well as the standard `"s3:PutObject"`.

You also need to tell the policy that you allow it to create objects within the S3 bucket. This is the policy JSON file I had to create manually because of the AWS UI bug (see above):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "polly:SynthesizeSpeech",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy your lambda function can use the Polly service, create and upload the MP3 files into your S3 bucket, and the device can play them back to any member of the public if you have your bucket set to allow public access.